I get an npm error code when trying install npm modules
I'm trying to do an "npm i" and I get the above error. The full error is as follows
npm error require() of ES Module /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/p-map/index.js from /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/lib/entry-index.js not supported.
npm error Instead change the require of index.js in /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/cacache/lib/entry-index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

I have found the entry-index.js file, but there is no import() statement for index.js.
Even if there was such a statement, I still do not know how to change the require() to a dynamic import() statement.
I do not know if it's appropriate to attach the entry-index.js file, or if so, where / how would I do that?
I cloned a github repository. cd into the subdirectory, then tried to run npm i.
I was expecting the npm modules to be installed. Instead I receive the error described above.
I have nodejs version 22.80 and npm version 10.8.3 installed on my manjaro linux dcomputer.
I am not sure what other information, if any, you might need to help me with this problem.

Can you share the github repository?

This is the repo - [link]https://github.com/jackyzha0/quartz - I was following their installation instructions - [link]https://quartz.jzhao.xyz/

Works as expected for me. Please try the following:

Manually remove node modules folder
Run the command below just in case there is any issue with npm:

npm cache clean --force

Then run npm i again


Thank you so much for your attempts to help. 1. There is no node-modules folder.   2. running npm cache clean --force gives me the exact same error as above.  3.  Should I try to uninstall / reinstall nodejs and npm?  Again, thank you!!!  VERY much appreciate your efforts!

I was able to install it with nod version 20. Could you please try uninstall version 22 and try again with a lower version?

I uninstalled / reinstalled my current node.js - (this is the version that is in my OS's repositories).  That didn't work.  Let me do some research on how to install a previous version on my manjaro desktop.  Thank you again for your time!

Maybe you can use  nvm to install multiple versions of nodejs. Check the aur package: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/nvm

Somehow, I really corrupted my system. I had to do a clean install.  Now I get an update_ref failed due to a locked ref file.  Currently researching this.  It looks like I may need to reinstall the repo, and start again.  So glad I have backups.  Will post here if I ever get it fixed!  Again, I am so very grateful for your persistence in helping.  I'm sorry for taking up your time because I don't know what I'm doing.  I appreciate your help.  I'm looking for how to upvote your responses, but not seeing it (I also have vision issues).  I want to give you the appropriate upvotes.

Okay ... I recloned the repository, copied my content over and all is working as it should!  Again @manosk, THANK YOU so very much for your asssitance!!!

Glad to hear that it finally worked... Good luck hacking!!!
